# What does ! and NR%2 means in this command?

Tags: awk

I have this command which will print every second line starting from the first line:

```
ls -l | awk '!(NR%2){print}'
```

I understand what happens in the first part (ls -l) but I don't understand the "!(NR%2)" part.

Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NR` is the current record (line, in your case) number, starting from 1, `%` is the modulus operator; `NR%2` is 0 when NR is even, and 1 when NR is odd.  `!` is a boolean negation, so`!(NR%2)` evaluates to true when NR is divisible by 2, and false when it is not.  So every other record is printed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation!