# split files to key value pair

Tags: awk, sed, grep

```
Input file
           - name: APPENV
             value: STAGING
           - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USER
             value: elastic
           - name: WRITE_LOGS_TO_ELASTICSEARCH
             value: "true"
           - name: version
             value: "5"
```

Expected output:

```
APPENV: STAGING
ELASTICSEARCH_USER: elastic
WRITE_LOGS_TO_ELASTICSEARCH: "true"
version: "5"
```

tried  `awk -F "e:" '{print $2}' filename`  to abstract only key and value, but need to align this as above output. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
awk '
sub(/^[[:space:]]+- name: /, ""){n=$0}
sub(/^[[:space:]]+value: /, ""){print n": "$0}'
```

Match and remove the `name:` /`value:`  labels, and print the remainder of both lines on a single line.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=": "} /^- name:/{val=$NF;next} {print val,$NF}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** simple explanation would be, firstly setting `OFS`(output field separator) as `:`  for all lines. In main `awk` program checking if line starts from `- name:` then assign last field value to variable val and using `next` will skip all further `awk` program statements from here. When this condition(line starts from `- name:`) is NOT TRUE then printing val and last field of that line.

---

---

***EDIT:*** In case your Input_file really has spaces before `- name:` then try following code.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=": "} /^[[:space:]]+- name:/{val=$NF;next} {print val,$NF}' Input_file
```

Comment: thanks, it gives the same output as of ```awk -F "e:" '{print $2}' filename``` which I have arrived at but not the desired expected output

Comment: @Prasad, my code was tested and worked fine, only thing was it was not giving `: `(colon spaces) in it, which I have fixed now, please try my edited code once and let me know how it goes then?

Comment: Still did not give the desired output.

Comment: But got it working with ``` awk -F "e:" '{print $2}' filename | awk 'NR%2{printf "%s: ",$0;next;}1' ```

Comment: @Prasad, not sure my command is tested well and fine. Could you please run a command like: `cat -v your_file`? This will let you know if you have control M characters or not, sometime if we have control M characters in file it will not allow command to run correctly. Run it on your Input_file and let me know then.

Comment: ```:~/tmp$ cat -v filename
           - name: APPENV
             value: STAGING
           - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USER
             value: elastic
           - name: WRITE_LOGS_TO_ELASTICSEARCH
             value: "true"
           - name: version
             value: "5" ```

Comment: ```Output
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=": "} /^- name:/{val=$NF;next} {print val,$NF}' filename
: APPENV
: STAGING
: ELASTICSEARCH_USER
: elastic
: WRITE_LOGS_TO_ELASTICSEARCH
: "true"
: version
: "5"


Expected output
/tmp$ awk 'sub(/^[[:space:]]+- name: /, ""){n=$0} sub(/^[[:space:]]+value: /, ""){print n": "$0}' filename
APPENV: STAGING
ELASTICSEARCH_USER: elastic
WRITE_LOGS_TO_ELASTICSEARCH: "true"
version: "5" ```

Comment: @Prasad, does your file really have spaces `           -name:` OR it has `-name:`? Because my code assumes that it doesn't start from space, let me know I will edit it then.

Comment: @Prasad, Please try my EDIT code and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Yes, It has spaces.  (yaml file)

Comment: @Prasad, oh ok then my EDIT code should work, try it out once.

Comment: yes, the edited code works. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a YAML file? In that case you should probably use a dedicated parser, e.g. [Mike Farah's yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) :

```
yq e '.[] | .name + ": " + .value' infile
```

Output:

```
APPENV: STAGING
ELASTICSEARCH_USER: elastic
WRITE_LOGS_TO_ELASTICSEARCH: true
version: 5
```

Tested with yq version 4.14.1.

Answer (score 1):

Also with `awk`:

```
awk -v FS=': ' '!(NR%2){s=$2} (NR%2){if (s) print s ":", $2}' file
APPENV: STAGING
ELASTICSEARCH_USER: elastic
WRITE_LOGS_TO_ELASTICSEARCH: "true"
version: "5"
```

- "What does ! and NR%2 means?" See: [What does ! and NR%2 means in this command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70770828/what-does-and-nr2-means-in-this-command)